# how i find the list of files which should contain both string patterns are present in a given directory

Tags: unix, shell-script

i have active directory which contain multiple subdirectories.i want to find the list of files which should contains the string patterns as "String1" and "String2" respectively

Comment: I'd use `ag` for that.

Comment: Could you give more details and an example?

Comment: i have different files like t1.js and t2.js and t3.js.only the file t3.js has two string patterns as "hello" and "world".i want to find the list of file should contain both the strings.which means my output become t3.js while using grep and find unix comands it results where ever the stings "hello" and "world"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this with find command:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'String1' {} \; -exec grep -l 'String2' {} +
```